# Installation date and virtual status of the machine( For Darwin, FreeBSD and NetBSD)

Tags: terminal, virtual-machine, freebsd, darwin, netbsd

How do I determine installation date (when the system was first booted) for Linux,Darwin, FreeBSD and NetBSD?  Also, Is there any way to get the virtual status of the these machines (whether the system is virtual or physical).  I need output using terminal commands.

For example,

Windows machine Installation date can be found using below command:

```
>Command:
>
>     ssh host systeminfo | grep -i original
>
>Output:
>
>     Original Install Date:     1/24/2014, 12:30:41 PM
```

Windows machine Virtual status of the machine can be found using below command:

```
>Command:
>
>    ssh host systeminfo | grep -i manufacturer
>
>Output:
>
>    OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
>    System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using vmware.

To check whether you are inside a VM use `vmware-checkvm` from open-vm-tools

Answer (score 0):

To guess if your machine is a virtual machine, use the following:

- Under Linux: use `lspci | grep -ic vmware` or `dmesg | grep -ic vmware` or `dmidecode | grep -ic vmware`
- Under OpenBSD: use `pcidump -v | grep -ic vmware` or `dmesg | grep -ic vmware`
- Under Darwin/Mac OS X: use `system_profiler | grep -ic vmware`

I think that FreeBSD and NetBSD also have the equivalent of the `pcidump` command, but I use mostly OpenBSD these days, so I am not 100% certain.

You can also try to search for the vmware string in `/var/log/messages` for instance, and the `dmesg | grep -ic vmware` should work on pretty much all platforms (with the caveat that your `dmesg` may be overwritten if the machine has been running for a long time).

All of these commands should return a numerical value. If this value is greater than zero, your machine is a virtual machine. Please note that the value may be different based on the machine and on the command, but a result greater than zero always indicates a virtual machine.

As an added bonus, if you are using Virtual Box, simply replace `vmware` by `virtualbox` and the commands should work exactly the same.

Here are the results on a Linux ***virtual*** machine:

```
# dmidecode | grep -ic vmware
4
# lspci | grep -ic vmware
35
```

And here are the results on a Linux ***physical*** machine:

```
# dmidecode | grep -ic vmware
0
lspci | grep -ic vmware
0
```

As far as guessing the installation date of a machine, this is not really easy. Try using the `find` command to look for the oldest file on the hard disk, but even that is an approximation, as a server may have been updated several times between today and the first time it was installed.

Comment: No, it works for Linux, OpenBSD and Darwin. I have tested these on all three OS, so I know they work. Actually for FreeBSD, you should take a look at `pciconf` and `devinfo` : they should work pretty much the same as the examples I gave.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD the date when the system was first booted is *not* recorded.

If you look at the dates of the subdirectories in the root directory, you will find a lot of them that point to the same date (but not the same time). That is the date that the system was either installed or updated.

You can see when the machine was *last* booted with

```
> sysctl kern.boottime
kern.boottime: { sec = 1438374739, usec = 930216 } Fri Jul 31 22:32:19 2015
```